# Need all the indexes documents in a single bucket, is there any way?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working on a use case that process on buckets returned by Terms aggregation.

In one scenario there is need to process on all indexed documents, Is there any way using Terms aggregation or any other that can return all the documents in a single bucket? So I don't have to underlying architecture to handle this single scenario

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain a few more things about your question. You want  to aggregate on all different indexes documents or  all document from the one index  ??

Comment: Need all document from the one index in a single bucket. Because underlying architecture works on buckets. 
There are many ways to get all the records but I need them to be returned in a bucket so the same flow can work for required scenario.

Comment: You may be able to use the [global](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-global-aggregation.html) aggregation for this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Scroll API of Elasticsearch. This is the suggested way of fetching all documents of an index.

[Scroll API](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-request-scroll.html)